# Add multiple values to python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am creating a dictionary as shown below and then adding values with given keys. But I am working with sequencing data, and some of the data will need to be entered multiple times, while other data should be entered only once. So currently I'm doing this:

```
my_dict = defaultdict(list)
my_dict[seq].append(read_seq)
```

The dictionary then looks something like this:

```
{'TTTT': ['AGTG', 'AGGG'], 'AAAA': ['AGAG', 'TGTG']})
```

My problem is that I would like to associate two separate strings with each key but add them only upon the addition of a new key and then never again. And these should be different from the values shown above:

So i'm imagining something like this, thanks:

```
{'TTTT': ['AGTG', 'AGGG'], ['string1'], ['string2'], 'AAAA': ['AGAG', 'TGTG'], ['string3'], ['string4']})
```

Comment: `{'TTTT': ['AGTG', 'AGGG'], ['string1'], ...` first element is a key:value pair, the second one is a normal string item.
You can't have a dictionary with some of the entries as kay:pair values and some as normal strings(values without keys).
Think about the structure you want to have your data in again. maybe use a dictionary and a list separately.

Comment: First of all, your expected output is not a valid python dictionary. Secondly,  you should explain how you are getting your expected dictionary with examples

Comment: I figured it wasn't. I can try and clarify, but I'm interested to see if there is a good way to associate multiple pieces of data with a single key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about holding a tuple or a dict as the value of your primary dict?
So instead of this(which cant quite exist in python):

```
{'TTTT': ['AGTG', 'AGGG'], ['string1'], ['string2'], 'AAAA': ['AGAG', 'TGTG'], ['string3'], ['string4']})
```

You will get:

```
{'TTTT': (['AGTG', 'AGGG'], ['string1'], ['string2']), 'AAAA': (['AGAG', 'TGTG'], ['string3'], ['string4'])}
```

This basically means a tuple of 3 elements for every key, the first one is your list and the second and third are your strings.
To implement that, define your defaultdict this way:

```
my_dict = defaultdict(lambda:([], [], []))
```

Then use `my_dict[0]` for the original string list, `my_dict[1]` and `my_dict[2]` for your strings.

An example for appending a key/value to this dict:

```
my_dict[seq][0].append(read_seq)
#And now your two strings:
my_dict[seq][1] = 'string1'
my_dict[seq][1] = 'string2'
```

If you don't want to hold your strings in a list(which you probably shouldn't), you can use a dict instead.Then it will look like:

```
{'TTTT': {'sequences':['AGTG', 'AGGG'], 'additional':('string1', 'string2')}, 'AAAA': {'sequences':['AGAG', 'TGTG'], 'additional':('string3', 'string4')}}
```

This will make adding key/values somewhat clearer:

```
my_dict = defaultdict(dict)
#...
my_dict[seq]['sequences'] = read_seq
#And now your two strings:
my_dict[seq]['additional'] = ('string1','string2')
```

I personally prefer the second option.

Comment: This looks great. But how do I append data to each key?

Comment: Holding the strings in a list does exactly what I want, so thank you. Using a dict gives me the following error: TypeError: `list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: when using the dict answer define: `my_dict = defaultdict(dict)` instead of `defaultdict(list)` and it should work